# Same Function Passing different parameter in same query getting the both output at same time

Tags: php, postgresql, function, return, parameter-passing

I am sending two parameter `From=2015-08-01` and `To=2015-08-31` is working fine. Then how to also passing parameter `(From2=2015-04-01 and  To2 =2015-08-31)` and getting the both output at same time. Please do not write any other functions. Please advise me.

**This is my output.php**

```
  $res1=$con->selectnonschoolround1($From,$To);
  while($row=pg_fetch_array($res1))
  {
    $r1=$row['non_slsc_qty'];
    $r2=$row['non_slst_qty'];
    $r3=$row['non_slot_qty'];
    $r4=$row['non_slsc_ben'];
    $r5=$row['non_slst_ben'];
    $r6=$row['non_slot_ben']; 
    $Total_qty_non_r1=$row['total_qty']; 
    $Total_ben_non_r1=$row['total_ben']; 
  }
```

**This is the class.php**

```
class DB_con
{

  function __construct()
  {
    $db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 
    dbname=mydb  user=postgres password=123");
  }
  public function selectnonschoolround1($From,$To)
  {
      $res1=pg_query("SELECT
      SUM(non_slsc_qty) as non_slsc_qty,
      SUM(non_slst_qty) as non_slst_qty,
      SUM(non_slot_qty) as non_slot_qty,
      SUM(non_slsc_ben) as non_slsc_ben,
      SUM(non_slst_ben) as non_slst_ben,
      SUM(non_slot_ben) as non_slot_ben,
      SUM(non_slsc_qty+non_slst_qty+non_slot_qty) AS total_qty,
      SUM(non_slsc_ben+non_slst_ben+non_slot_ben) AS total_ben
      FROM table  where date BETWEEN '$From' AND '$To'");
      return $res1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass function parameter as an array and then you need to check if parameter is array or not using PHP function is_array(). If its an array then loop through that array and execute the query with "from" and "to" indexes but, in this case you need to return an array from the executed query. If its not an array the keep the code as it is in your else part. In this you can use the same function for multiple value or for single values. Just keep in mind that the params should be proper. Hope this will help you out :)

Try this code and make the changes as per your need :).

```
class DB_con
{

    function __construct()
    {
        //code
    }

    public function selectNonSchoolRound1($arr, $from = '', $to = '')
    {
        if (is_array($arr)) {
            $returnArr = array();
            foreach ($arr as $ars) {
                $res1 = pg_query("your query using ".$ars['from'].$ars['to']);
                array_push($returnArr, $res1);
            }
            return $returnArr;
        } else {
            $res1 = pg_query("your query using ".$from.$to.'variabls');
            return $res1;
        }

    }

}

try {
    $arr = array('0' => 
        array('from' => '2015-08-01', 'to' => '2015-08-31'), 
        '1' => array('from' => '2015-08-01', 'to' => '2015-08-31')
    );
    $obj = new DB_con();
    $result = $obj->selectNonSchoolRound1($arr);
    // loop here with the $result variable
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```